# How to find name from string using Regex in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, text-extraction

Here is my code , i have written separate function for regex to extract name pattern, passing Regex Pattern with two strings to the function, function matches either one pattern from two input string or it will return 'No_Value'.

```
 function getName(narration_1, narration_2, regex) {
try {
    // regex = JSON.parse(regex);
    regex = regex.find((item) => { console.log("Item", item); return (new RegExp(item, 'ig').test(narration_1) === true || new RegExp(item, 'ig').test(narration_2) === true)});
    console.log("Regex", regex);
    let narration = (!!regex) ? (new RegExp(regex, 'ig').test(narration_1) ? narration_1 : narration_2) : null;
    let name = (!!narration && narration.match(regex)) ? (!narration.match(regex)[1] ? 'NO_VALUE' : narration.match(regex)[1].trim()) : 'NO_VALUE';
    console.log(name);
    return name;
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Err", e);
    // throw new Error(e);

}
 }

let string1 ="OPERATION"
let string2 = "退回自動轉賬 WRITE SOMEOPERATIONS TO MR . MANOJ-THOMAS"
let regex =  ["MR (.*?) (?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])"];
getName(string1, string2, regex);
```

I want to extract name from above string 2 MANOJ-THOMAS however the name appears it can also need to match "Mr.","MR .",MR.","MR.  ".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way:

```
function getName(narration_1, narration_2, regex) {
    let name = 'NO_VALUE';
    let narration = narration_1.match(regex) || narration_2.match(regex);
    if (narration) { // if any match was found in either narration_1 or _2
        name = narration[1]; // match method filled this array
        console.log("name found: " + name);
    }
    return name;
}

let regex = new RegExp(".*mr\\s?\\.\\s?(.+)", "i");
let narration_1 = "退回自動轉賬 WRITE SOMEOPERATIONS TO MR . MANOJ-THOMAS";
let narration_2 = "OPERATION";

getName(narration_1, narration_2, regex);
```

Note that this assumes that the name always is **at the end of the string**. If that is not the case you will have to extend the regular expression to exclude whatever comes after.